# Incorrect collation error with right database collaction

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sql-server, configuration, database

Doing a fresh SharePoint Foundation 2013 installation I get an error:

> 'The database name located at the specified database server has an
>   incorrect collation. Rebuild the database with the
>   Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS collation or create a new database using
>   the Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS collation'

But I checked the database and has the right collation!

```
SELECT name, collation_name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = 'SharePoint_Config2013'
```

result:

```
SharePoint_Config2013   Latin1_General_CI_AI_KS_WS
```

OS: Windows Server 2008 R2, SQL Server: 10.50.4042.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output shows that your database doesn't have the correct collation - 'AI' is not the same as 'AS'!

The output from a similar query against a default SharePoint 2016 configuration database gives:

> SharePoint_Config2013   Latin1_General_CI_AI_KS_WS

AI means accent-insensitive, i.e. the system is treating a letter with an accent as the same as a letter without.